# How to add MSI file into vb.net setup

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-installer, installation, setup-deployment

I have setup of application.

The Prerequisite of my application is SQLServer2005_BC(MSI file)if i have manually install Then my application is working but i don't want to do like that.while installing setup only i want to install msi file without doing any clicks.

How do i add msi file in setup Project ?
I have tried with custom action but no result....

Answer (score 1):

You can't install it from a Visual Studio setup project using a custom action because recursive MSI installs aren't allowed (yours calling the SQL one).

For VS setups where you need custom prerequisites, the BootStrap Manifest Generator is what people generally use. It generates a setup.exe that will install prerequisites then your MSI. It's a data driven tool where you say how to detect and install that SQL MSI, usually based on the MSI's ProductCode that you can find by opening it with Orca.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx